# Type Issues When Writing a Nested dictionary to a plist (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, nested, plist

I'm trying to write a dictionary with multiple layers of nesting to a progress list (plist) in Swift. However, for some reason one of the dictionaries is being treated as an array when I inspect the plist leading to a bunch of type issues in my project.

Here is the original nested dictionary:

I've attached a screenshot showing the plist structure and another showing the original data structure, I know you aren't meant to show photos of code but this text editor isn't formatting it properly and is mistreating the angle brackets

[original data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltk3v.png)

[screenshot showing plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4uKq.png)

UPDATED

Ok I added one more key value pair at the topmost level and its being written to the dictionary correctly. The problem I'm having now is that I can write to the plist just fine but when I try to read from it all I get is nil.

```
func initializeProgress() {
let directories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)

if let documents = directories.first {
    if let urlDocuments = NSURL(string: documents) {
        let urlProgress = urlDocuments.URLByAppendingPathComponent("progress.plist")
        let progressDict = NSDictionary(dictionary: ["AP Biology": ["Misc": ["correct": 0, "incorrect": 0, "totalInSection": 0, "percentDone": 0],
            "Basics": ["correct": 0, "incorrect": 0, "totalInSection": 0, "percentDone": 0],
            "Essential Chemistry": ["correct": 0, "incorrect": 0, "totalInSection": 0, "percentDone": 0],
            "Molecules of Life": ["correct": 0, "incorrect": 0, "totalInSection": 0, "percentDone": 0]]])
        progressDict.writeToFile(urlProgress.path!, atomically: true)

    }

}
```

}

```
func retrieveAndSetProgress() {
let directories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)

let documents = directories.first
let urlDocuments = NSURL(string: documents!)
let urlProgress = urlDocuments!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("progress.plist")
print(NSDictionary(contentsOfURL: urlProgress))
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: urlProgress, options: NSDataReadingOptions())
    print(data)
progress = NSDictionary(contentsOfURL: urlProgress)! as! Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, Int>>>

}
```

`progress` is a global variable and the last line of the second method produces an error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: Works fine for me, post the code where you write/read the plist

Comment: I was actually able to get it to work correctly by adding another key value pair at the topmost level of the dictionary. The problem I'm having now is that when I try to read it back into my project, it's nil? I'll post the read/write code momentarily. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @dan I've updated the question and added the two methods I use to read and write, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
print(NSDictionary(contentsOfURL: urlProgress))
```

to

```
print(NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: urlProgress.absoluteString))
```

It can read it then. I just tested on a playground